# When is the Blu-ray release of Kaze Tachinu/The Wind Rises?

Tags: the-wind-rises

I have been searching for the (Japanese) release date of the Kaze Tachinu (The Wind Rises) Blu-ray.

As U.S. cinema release is in February 2014, so me being in the Netherlands means it might arrive in 2016.

So, when is the Japanese Blu-ray release?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As near as I can tell, there is (as of 22 Oct 2013) no announced release date for the Blu-ray/DVD version of *The Wind Rises*. However, the recent history of Ghibli films suggests a pattern.

```
FILM                     IN THEATERS    HOME VIDEO RELEASE
Arrietty                 July 2010      June 2011
From Up on Poppy Hill    July 2011      June 2012
The Wind Rises           July 2013      _________
```

As the astute reader will infer, this suggests that *The Wind Rises* will probably be released (on home video) in June 2014 or thereabouts.

---

**UPDATE:** *The Wind Rises* will be available on home video (Blu-ray and DVD) in Japan [on **June 18, 2014**](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E9%A2%A8%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AC-Blu-ray-%E5%AE%AE%E5%B4%8E%E9%A7%BF/dp/B00J2NX8NW/ref=sr_1_1?s=dvd&ie=UTF8&qid=1396295586&sr=1-1&keywords=%E9%A2%A8%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AC), just as I surmised.

Comment: i wonder if the pattern is deliberate or by luck, it's almost like with Square releasing 3 new Main Final Fantasy games on Home Console before moving onto the next generation

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the Netherlands does have a theatrical release before senshin's predicted DVD/Bluray release (and long before 2016).  [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2013293/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) says that you should be able to view *Kaze Tachinu* on May 1, 2014.

Answer (score -1):

can buy here and get it shipped http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/VWBS-1529

[image]