# The Wind Rises English release date?

Tags: hayao-miyazaki, the-wind-rises

I can not wait to watch "The Wind Rises" Movie, which is Miyazaki's final film. Is there any news about its English release date?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about future events with regard to the production of an anime or manga; such details are only known to the creators of said works and should be checked on anime news sources.

Comment: yes, thanks really, but just I wonder maybe someone knows! ...

Comment: for a fact i know The Wind Rises opens in U.S. theaters on February 21st, 2014. You should refrain from asking such questions in the future again ok :)

Comment: yes, I am newbie here actually, but cause I can not wait until watch it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also see https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5549/when-is-the-blu-ray-release-of-kaze-tachinu-the-wind-rises

Comment: Technically, the policy is only against asking about *unannounced* future releases, while a release of this has been announced for a while, so I'm not going to vote to close. On the other hand, this information is already located in hundreds of other places on the web, including [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wind_Rises#Release). You should check those before asking this kind of question here.

Comment: I see it actually, but cause it was asked on Oct. 2013, Now I wonder there are new news for it!

Comment: really I know, also I google it, BUT I suggest that I can discuss like this Question here with lover of anime movies, Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According a [press release](http://collider.com/the-wind-rises-release-date-us/) to Disney dated September 11, 2013:

> The film is slated for limited release in North American theaters on Feb. 21, 2014, and expanded release on Feb. 28, 2014, under the Touchstone Pictures banner. The Wind Rises will also open for Academy Award qualification engagements in New York and Los Angeles Nov. 8-14, 2013, showcasing the original film in Japanese with English subtitles.